# node.js mongodb select document by _id node-mongodb-native

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I'm trying to select a document by id

I've tried:

```
collection.update({ "_id": { "$oid": + theidID } }

collection.update({ "_id": theidID }

collection.update({ "_id.$oid": theidID }}
```

Also tried:

```
collection.update({ _id: new ObjectID(theidID ) }
```

This gives me an error 500...

```
var mongo = require('mongodb')
var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
var o_id = new BSON.ObjectID(theidID );

collection.update({ _id: o_id }
```

None of these work. How to select by _id?

Comment: `collection.find({"_id": ObjectId(theidID)})` should work.

Comment: @Bugai13 I gave up and ended up assigning a custom ID for every doc.

Comment: I need this for a select/find (not an update, even).  Any luck?

Comment: It won't work if you don't have a reference to the right serializer.

Comment: @BernieHackett this method does not work for node runtime 12.13 with mongodb version 3.4. It gives the error described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453507/argument-passed-in-must-be-a-single-string-of-12-bytes

Comment: @Bernie Hackett . 10 years passed . Still saves someone's arse! Appreciated and upvoted comment

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var o_id = new mongo.ObjectID(theidID);
collection.update({'_id': o_id});
```

Comment: Year 2016 - still works ok.
If no maby you had `native_parser:false` - check Raphael reply below

Comment: This works. Make sure the you are calling `ObjectID()` on `require('mongodb')` and not on `require('mongodb').MongoClient`

Comment: By this way I got `mongoClient.ObjectID is not a constructor` error.

Comment: Now `ObjectID` is deprecated, one should use `ObjectId` instead

Answer (score 81):

This the approach that worked for me.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var get_by_id = function(id, callback) {
  console.log("find by: "+ id);
  get_collection(function(collection) {
    collection.findOne({"_id": new ObjectId(id)}, function(err, doc) {
       callback(doc);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 25):

now you can just use this:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var o_id = new ObjectID("yourObjectIdString");
....
collection.update({'_id': o_id});
```

You can see documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#objectid)

Comment: is it possible to use ES6 style `import` statement instead of `require('mongodb').ObjectID`?

Answer (score 12):

With `native_parser:false`:

```
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSONPure;
var o_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(theidID);
```

With `native_parser:true`:

```
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSONNative;
var o_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(theidID);
```

Answer (score 10):

I just used this code in Node.js app in controller file, and it works:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
...
User.findOne({_id:ObjectId("5abf2eaa1068113f1e")})
.exec(function(err,data){
   // do stuff
})
```

do not forget to install "mongodb" before, and if you are using encryption of your passwords with bcrypt with "presave", be sure that you will not encrypt password after each modification of the record in DB.

Answer (score 9):

mongodb 4.0.0

```
/* get id */
const id        = request.params.id; // string "5d88733be8e32529c8b21f11"

/* set object id */
const ObjectId  = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

/* filter */
collection.update({ 
    "_id": ObjectId(id)
} )
```

mongodb 5.0.0

```
"_id": new ObjectId(id)
```

stackoverflow.com: [new ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75553265/i-cant-delete-a-data-from-mongodb-objectid-class-constructor-error)

Answer (score 4):

ObjectId reports deprecated when called inside find() function in "mongodb": "^4.1.2" if the ObjectId is imported like this

```
const ObjectId  = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

instead, when I import it with named import there is no deprecated warning

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
```

then I can call it regularly

```
const findResult = await collection.find({_id: ObjectId(id)}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.
Using mongoDB

`const mongoDB = require('mongodb')`

Then at the bottom where I am making my express get call.

```
router.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
var o_id = new mongoDB.ObjectID(id);

const usersCollection = database.collection('users');

usersCollection.findOne({
  _id: o_id
})

.then(userFound => {
  if (!userFound){
    return res.status(404).end();
  }
  // console.log(json(userFound));
  return res.status(200).json(userFound)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));

 });`
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends upon the variable type you are passing in as the id.  I pulled an object id by doing a query and storing my account_id as the ._id attribute.  Using this method you simply query using the mongo id.

```
// begin account-manager.js
var MongoDB   = require('mongodb').Db;
var dbPort      = 27017;
var dbHost      = '127.0.0.1';
var dbName      = 'sample_db';
db = new MongoDB(dbName, new Server(dbHost, dbPort, {auto_reconnect: true}), {w: 1});
var accounts = db.collection('accounts');

exports.getAccountById = function(id, callback)
{ 
  accounts.findOne({_id: id},
    function(e, res) {  
    if (e) {
        callback(e)
    }
    else {
        callback(null, res)
    }

  });
}
// end account-manager.js

// my test file
var AM = require('../app/server/modules/account-manager');

it("should find an account by id", function(done) {

AM.getAllRecords(function(error, allRecords){
  console.log(error,'error')
  if(error === null) {
    console.log(allRecords[0]._id)
    // console.log('error is null',"record one id", allRecords[0]._id)
    AM.getAccountById(          
      allRecords[0]._id,
      function(e,response){
        console.log(response,"response")
        if(response) {
          console.log("testing " + allRecords[0].name + " is equal to " + response.name)
          expect(response.name).toEqual(allRecords[0].name);
          done();    
        } 
      }
    )  
  } 
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mongosee, you can simplify the function

FindById:

this replace in mongodb: `"_id" : ObjectId("xyadsdd434434343"),`

```
example:

// find adventure by id and execute
Adventure.findById('xyadsdd434434343', function (err, adventure) {});
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById

Answer (score 0):

I'm using client `"mongodb": "^3.6.2"` and server version `4.4.1`

```
// where 1 is your document id
const document = await db.collection(collection).findOne({ _id: '1' })
console.log(document)
```

If you want to copy and paste here's all you need.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const uri = '...'
const mongoDb = '...'
const options = {}
;(async () => {
  const client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
  await client.connect()
  const db = client.db(mongoDb)
  const document = await db.collection(collection).findOne({ _id: '1' })
  console.log(document)
)}()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose, the `Model.findById()` function is used to find one document by its `_id`. The `findById()` function takes in a single parameter, the document id. It returns a promise that resolves to the Mongoose document if MongoDB found a document with the given `id`, or `null` if no document was found.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({ _id: Number }, { versionKey: false });
const Model = mongoose.model('MyModel', schema);

await Model.create({ _id: 1 });

// `{ _id: 1 }`
await Model.findById(1);

// `null` because no document was found
await Model.findById(2);
```

When you call `findById(_id)`, Mongoose calls `findOne({ _id })` under the hood. That means `findById()` triggers `findOne()` [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({ _id: Number }, { versionKey: false });
schema.pre('findOne', function() {
  console.log('Called `findOne()`');
});
const Model = mongoose.model('MyModel', schema);
await Model.create({ _id: 1 });

// Prints "Called `findOne()`" because `findById()` calls `findOne()`
await Model.findById(1);
```

[Mongoose casts queries to match your schema.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/query_casting.html) That means if your `_id` is a [MongoDB ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), you can pass the `_id` as a string and Mongoose will convert it to an ObjectId for you.

```
const _id = '5d273f9ed58f5e7093b549b0';
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({ _id: mongoose.ObjectId }, { versionKey: false });
const Model = mongoose.model('MyModel', schema);

await Model.create({ _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) });

typeof _id; // 'string'
// `{ _id: '5d273f9ed58f5e7093b549b0' }`
const doc = await Model.findById(_id);

typeof doc._id; // 'object'
doc._id instanceof mongoose.Types.ObjectId; // true
```

[Source](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/find-by-id#:%7E:text=In%20Mongoose%2C%20the%20Model.,if%20no%20document%20was%20found.)