# mongodb-wrapper and ObjectId of an entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to select/delete entries from my mongodb via node.js and mongodb-wrapper.
I get the id of the entry as a string via a http request.
Then I want to delete the entry with the specific id.

```
app.delete('/posts/:id', function(req, res) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
db.posts.remove({"_id": req.params.id}, function(err) {
    if (err) return res.send(err.message, 500); // server error
    res.send(200);
  })
res.send("ok");
});
```

But this is not working. I already tried several ways but nothing deletes the entry. I have red something that I must convert the string into a ObjectId but until now I didn't found anything how to do this via mongodb-wrapper.

Comment: [This][1] question might be able to help you out.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902569/node-js-mongodb-select-document-by-id-node-mongodb-native

Comment: I already was there... but I did look again and a quite deeper and found my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using: `{"_id": req.params.id}` you are querying for a string rather than an objectId. You need to create an `ObjectId` from the string to use it:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var oid = new ObjectID(req.params.id);
```

be aware that this will throw an error if the data in req.params.id can not be converted to a valid ObjectID.