# Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongoDB collection contains the following data

```
db.stack.find()
{ "_id" : "8GieRu" }
```

The _id is not single String of 12 bytes,

As per the MongoDB document of [ObjectID][1], ***id (string) – Can be a 24 byte hex string, 12 byte binary string or a Number.***

Using Mongoose this collection is accessed using this Json

```
{"_id" : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("8GieRu")}
```

and throws the below error

```
/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:35
    throw new Error("Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or
          ^
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
    at new ObjectID (/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:35:11)

  [1]: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html
```

Mongoose is strictly checking the ObjectId of fixed length, how can i pass Object_id using mongoose with the given length

Comment: Note: ObjectId is 12 byte, but you can use **string id** with more than 24 byte length and not in hex format, it can easily test with mongo shell **db.users.insert({ _id : '0123454678ببیبسی9012345678900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005'})**, I even used Arabic character in _id, Its OK

Comment: You should pass ObjectID  not ObjectId, pay attention to the last "D" it is uppercase

Comment: Three Things: **First**: use ```ObjectID``` instead of ```ObjectId```. **Second:** ```ObjectID``` needs at least 12bytes string. It means for example ```"1234567890ab"``` and **Third**, you can directly do ```new ObjectID("1234567890ab")```

Answer (score 17):

You mix two concepts here.

While "_id" can have any value (even subdocument like `{firstName:'Foo',lastName:'Simpson'}`, "ObjectId" has a fixed set of types with some restrictions, as the error message correctly states.

So your statement should be

```
{'_id':'putWhatEverYouWantHere'}
```

Comment: Some interesting pages in the documentation : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/  and  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#the-id-field

Comment: Is there anyway to only-hide this error? even when wrong value set. or to beautify it?

Answer (score 9):

I had the problem in my router order:

```
app.get('/jobs', controllers.jobs.getAllJobs);
app.get('/jobs/karriere', controllers.jobs.getAllJobsXML);

app.get('/jobs/:id', controllers.jobs.getJob);
app.get('/jobs/:id/xml', controllers.jobs.getJobXML);
```

I defined /jobs/karriere **after** /jobs/:id so the application thought that "karriere" was an ObjectID and returned the error. The code above is the working one.

Comment: How did you fix it for `/jobs/:id`? This is exactly the issue I am having now.

Comment: I did this in `/jobs/:id` route:  
`if (!ObjectId.isValid(id)) return res.json({ error: "Invalid Campaign Id" })`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the method you are using in client and server side match. This error also shows when you have e.g. `GET` being sent from client side and `POST` required on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing any

```
ObjectID undefinded
```

If the ObjectID is undfined thaen this error will come.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using mongoose. and I am not able to query with something like this:

```
{ "_id" : "8GieRu" }
```

Until I bumped into my model file and specified this line counter.model.js

```
var CounterSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  sequence_value: Number
})
```

Notice that I specified the data type as string for _id in my model.
and the, in my query, I didn't need to convert string to ObjectId.

Query now works as simple as what the filter:

```
{ "_id" : "8GieRu" }
```

Answer (score 0):

same problem faced by me but after a RND . I identified that i passed wrong {Id:Undefined} so problem occured so please firstly check your Id which you passed in URL.

```
      Error = "http://localhost:4000/api/deleteBook/Undefined"
      Right = "http://localhost:4000/api/deleteBook/5bb9e79df82c0151fc0cd5c8"
```