# Not able to remove record from mongoDB nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to remove a record from MongoDB using nodeJS. But the record is not getting deleted.

Please find the below code:

```
exports.remove = function(studentId, cb) {
var collection = db.get().collection('students');
collection.remove({_id: studentId}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
      throw err;
  }
  else {
     cb(err);
     console.log("Record deleted.");
  }
 });
 }
```

I have tried the studentId with ObjectID() as below:

```
exports.remove = function(studentId, cb) {
var collection = db.get().collection('students');
collection.remove({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(studentId)}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
      throw err;
  }
  else {
     cb(err);
     console.log("Record deleted.");
  }
  });
  }
```

But getting an error as :
"Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"
Please help on this issue!!!!!

Comment: Not to sound like a nitwit, but "records" do not exist in MongoDB. They are called `document`s. What is your ID type?

Comment: @GamerNebulae I am new to NodeJS and MongoDB. Thanks for the information. I am not sure about the ID type. This is the default Id generated by MongoDB while insering a document. I am tring to delete using the same generated Id.

Comment: Default, Mongo uses an `ObjectID`.

Comment: Have you ever looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453507/argument-passed-in-must-be-a-single-string-of-12-bytes

Comment: @GamerNebulae I went through the link above. my _id is 24 hex characters and still giving the error "Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters". I tried with out using ObjectID, but its successfully geting executed but the docements not deleted from mongoDB.

Comment: You are providing an invalid Object ID. It is always best to leave the objectID created by mongoDB alone and create/use some other fields to uniquely identify documents. Please console and double check the _id to be a valid mongoDB object ID

Comment: @Nidhin David - I have used the same objectID that I pulled from MongoDB. But when I tried to execute the same, the statement executed but the document not removed from DB. I found that need to use new mongodb.ObjectID() method to get the objectID from the string notation of objectID that I got from DB. But while using the same I am getting an error as - "Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters".

Answer (score 0):

When you call your remove function,  make sure you are passing an actual string as the first argument, not a numeric.

Or, in your remove function,  cast studentId to a string like so:

```
collection.remove({_id: studentId.toString()},  function(err) {...
```

Comment: I tried this, but the record in not getting deleted from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

1. at first, you should remove unnecessary **`get()`** method on db:
   `var collection = db.collection('students');`
2. next step, don't dismiss **`new`** keyword, it's just fine to only wrap:
   `collection.remove({_id: mongodb.ObjectID(studentId)}, function(err) {`

Comment: I am using a db.js to DB conect and close and uses get() method to return the current state of the connection:
exports.get = function() {
  return state.db
}
I have tried the second step, but its giving the same error as before : "Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"

Answer (score 0):

perhaps creating the id from this method will help :

```
mongodb.ObjectID.createFromHexString(studentId);
```

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html

Comment: I will try this and let you know the same.
Thanks

Comment: I tried the same but getting the same issue. Mean while I have tried to log the _id and its length, surprisingly the length is getting as 25. Please find the _id an its length out in the console:
_id:576aba09090560f80bd2caaa
Length---->25

Comment: I got the solution for this issue. I have posted the same here .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this, why I was getting the error - "Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters" when using new mongodb.ObjectID(studentId). I want this to be shared with all of us.

My angularJS controller is as follows:

```
mainApp.controller("deleteStudentController", function($scope,$http) {
var resData = {};
$scope.student = {};
var urlGet = "/students/all";
$http.get(urlGet)
.then(function(response) {
$scope.students = angular.fromJson(response.data);
});
$scope.deleteStudent = function(){
var urlDelete = "/students/remove:"+$scope.studentRadio;
$http.delete(urlDelete)
.success(function(response, status, headers, config){
    $scope.output = "Student successfully deleted.";
})
.error(function(response, status, headers, config){
    $scope.output = "Error in processing. Please try again.";
});
}
});
```

In the above controller we can see the URL as

```
var urlDelete = "/students/remove:"+$scope.studentRadio;
```

which inturn calls my node controller :

```
router.delete("/remove:studId", function(req,res){
Students.remove(req.params.studId, function(err) {
if (err) {
  throw err;
}
else {
  var respOut = "Student deleted";
  res.send(respOut);
}
});
});
```

The Angular code is setting the endpoint like this:

```
"/students/remove:"+$scope.studentRadio
```

I want the : to be there, so the URL will look something like this:

```
/students/remove:576c1d4781aaa4f16a68af24
```

The Express route is as below:

```
router.delete("/remove:studId", ...)
```

: is a special character in Express routes (it declares a named parameter called studId). This means that the route will take everything after /remove to be the value of studId, including the colon that's in the URL. So req.params.studId is :576c1d4781aaa4f16a68af24, which has a length of 25 characters.

If we want to use this sort of URL scheme, we need to make the colon to be part of the match by escaping it (so it loses its special meaning):

router.delete("/remove\::studId", ...)