# Why is `_id` not accepting by custom string using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, apollo-server

I'm trying to make an `_id` field based off the title for `topic` object I've defined in my server. Here's the the schema.

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express')

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Topic @key(fields: "name") {
        name: String,
        desc: String,
        body: String,
        subject: [String]
    }
`
```

And then here's the resolver

```
const resolvers = {
     Mutation: {
        addTopic(parent, args, context, info) {
            const { name, desc, body, subject } = args
            const topicObj = new Topic({
                _id: name,
                name,
                desc,
                body,
                subject
            })
            return topicObj.save()
                .then(result => {
                    return{ ...result._doc}
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting is `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "MyTopic" (type string) at path "_id"`.

Not too surprisingly, when I cast it manually with `_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(name)` I get the `Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters` error.

I must be misunderstanding, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453507/argument-passed-in-must-be-a-single-string-of-12-bytes) post lead me to believe my first approach is the right one so I'm not sure what to do to get it working.

I think I have to find some way to tell Mongoose not to try casting it but I'm not sure if that's what I should be doing.

---

Mongoose Model

```
const TopicSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    subject: {
        type: [String],
        required: true
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you also post your Mongoose schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't declared your `_id` on your Mongoose Schema, Mongoose is  defaulting to an `ObjectId` type for your documents' `_id` instead of a `String` one that leads to the error.

To solve this you can declare the `_id` in your schema like this:

```js
const TopicSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    subject: {
        type: [String],
        required: true
    }
})
```

You can read more here: [How to set _id to db document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760829/how-to-set-id-to-db-document-in-mongoose)