# Finding MongoDB documents by _id failing on the type of ObjectId

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, async-await, objectid

I'm struggling to find MongoDB documents by their `_id` field in my ReactJS project.

My collection has documents that looks like so (for example):

```
    _id: ObjectId("5f6651112efc19f33b34fc39")
    title: "This is a title"
    status: true
```

I'm using this (greatly simplified) code in a function to find the documents that match the `id` passed in:

```
const id = '5f6651112efc19f33b34fc39';
await mongoCollection.find({_id:ObjectId(id)});
```

`ObjectId` is defined like so:

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Yet even if I hard coded the `id` variable to be the ObjectId string from the document in my database, it fails with this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid ObjectId, ObjectId.id must be either a string or a Buffer, but is [{"type":"Buffer","data":[]}]`

Printing out `id` and `ObjectId(id)` before the `await` line results in the following:

[image: Console.log screenshot]

How should I be satisfying this warning?

Edit: I'm defining my app/collection like so:

```
const app = new Realm.App({ id: "<app-id>", timeout: 10000 });
const mongo = app.services.mongodb('mongodb-atlas');
const mongoCol = mongo.db('<databaseName>').collection('<collectionName>');
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5186713/8079581

Comment: @matrixersp Strangely enough that doesn't work either. I get the same error in my original post. I'm able to use ```find()``` on any other field in my collection just fine. :(

Comment: did you try with `new`?

Comment: @RisingSun yep. Exactly like the accepted answer in the first comment of this chain.

Comment: try passing `ObjectId(id)` straight to `find()`. also, check out `findOne` and `findByID` methods

Comment: Passing ObjecrtId(id) directly and findOne produce the same errors. I believe findByID is part of mongoose, which I'm not (yet) using in this project...maybe it's worth using it though.

Comment: So maybe it's a bug. Have you tried using BSON's ObjectId instead? Same error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a known [BUG](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1779), try to use `bson` like:

```
const bson = require('bson');

const id = '5f6651112efc19f33b34fc39';
const bsonObjectId = new bson.ObjectId(id);
await mongoCollection.find({_id: bsonObjectId });
```

Comment: Holy heck this worked! Much appreciated for finding this!

Answer (score -2):

Try just _id instead of "_id"

```
const id = "5f6651112efc19f33b34fc39"
await mongoCollection.find({_id:ObjectId(id)});
```

Like this!