# I can't delete a data from mongoDb ObjectId class constructor error

Tags: mongodb, crud, delete-operator, objectid

I have written a express index.js to simple crud operation in mongodb. the item is the params I can console.log as mongodb Id however, ObjectId buildin function giving me a an class constructor error that it cannot inboked without 'new'.

```
const express = require("express");
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion, ObjectId } = require("mongodb");

const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://<hiddenuser>:<hiddenPass>@cluster0.9mathic.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});
const run = async () => {
  try {
    const userCollection = client
      .db("simple-node-mongo-server")
      .collection("mongo_crud_server");

    //post user data in db
    app.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
      const user = req.body;
      console.log(user);
      const result = await userCollection.insertOne(user);
      res.send(result);
    });

    //reading data of user
    app.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
      const query = {};
      const cursor = userCollection.find(query);
      const users = await cursor.toArray();
      res.send(users);
    });

    //deleting a user
    app.delete("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
      // console.log('trying to delete', id);
      const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
      console.log(query)
      // const result = await userCollection.deleteOne(query);
      // console.log(result);
      // res.send(result);
    });

  } finally {
  }
};
run().catch(console.dir);

//raw api hit
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening port 5000`);
});
```

error it shows

```
C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\index.js:45
      const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
                           ^

TypeError: Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\index.js:45:28
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at param (C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at param (C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:376:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:421:3)
    at next (C:\Users\sdman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mongo-project\mongo_crud_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)

Node.js v18.13.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've tried 'ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,'

Comment: `const query = { _id: new ObjectId(id) };`

Answer (score 2):

To solve the error, you can add the `new` keyword before `ObjectId` to create a new instance of the class:

```
const query = { _id: new ObjectId(id) };
```

Answer (score 0):

this part of the code:

```
 const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
```

you are doing right converting the id string to a MongoDB object id, just need to slightly modify to ***new* ObjectId(id)** so it creates a new instance of ObjectId